# Am I a spammer?

Tags: support, comments, spam

The question is raised in comments to these two stackoverflow questions (one borked as the submit check only allows me one link):

[Rebol how to parse A B syntax Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452239/rebol-how-to-parse-a-b-syntax-error)

[Rebol parse rule with compose deep and append function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458139/rebol-parse-rule-with-compose-deep-and-append-function)

The simple answer is no, and I am happy to provide evidence towards that answer.

The discussion though is best conducted here rather than in comments scattered across other threads. At the moment, it is simply diluting the responses with off-topic material.

Is there anyway to consolidate the comments here and then take it from there?

Comment: Is this one of those questions on existentialism?

Comment: I'm a little confused. Are you asking about silky's off-the-cuff comment that you seem to be answering all the REBOL questions? I don't see him calling you a spammer anywhere.

What here warrants discussion?

Comment: @Adam: Silky's comments do not use the word spammer. He/she seems to be raising the possibility that Rebol Tutorial and I are engaged in an "advertising scheme" (the term he/she does use). I've used "spam" as a shorthand for that.  The question of whether we are spamming is one that properly belongs on Meta, not in comments to technical questions. Hence my re-asking it in the proper place, so it can get the attention it deserves....Thanks to Diago for fixing the links in the original post.

Comment: If you have to ask... <g/d/r>

Comment: @Joel: I did not initiate the question...Just lifted Silky's implied question out of comments and into its own question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The behaviour of both you and REBOL Tutorial is acceptable.

The *name* REBOL Tutorial sounds like spam, although if he (she or they) intend to gradually ask more and more intro level REBOL questions, (and thereby become a tutorial) that is fine too. As long as each question is self-contained, and they are obeying the rules (no duplicates, upvoting answers, and marking accepted, etc.) then their behaviour is fine.

All they are doing is asking questions about REBOL. Nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 3):

Considering the name of the poster being Rebol Tutorial and apart from the function definition in the question there is no real meat to it, I can definitly see why it is considered spam.

Maybe by providing a detailed question with an answer this won't be considered as such, but I have to admit having seen the name Rebol Tutorial around I have always been wary of it being a spam account if it wasn't for the reputation score.

Comment: +1 for the confirmation that the OP isn't just being paranoid, but unless Sunanda and Rebol Tutorial are the same person, then we've got two individuals contributing to their languages' content on SO...  I still feel like I'm missing something...

Comment: Rebol Tutorial's #1 voted question is... "how can spammers circumvent captcha"! :)

Answer (score 3):

What you're doing is no different (and I'll argue even less intrusive) than when the R community [invaded SO with questions about the R language](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/stack-overflow-flash-mobs/).

Comment: That would be true if what I was doing was part of some sort of team plan. It was not. All I was doing was answering questions I'd noticed. I have no idea if Reboltutorial had some other motive, though that has been suggested elsewhere too [see http://www.rebol.org/aga-display-posts.r?post=r3wp146x3800 and onwards for example]

Answer (score 0):

Funny, I just stumbled upon this while searching on Google :)

You all paranoïds, I'm a Rebol Newbie, that is stated on my blog, I was learning Rebol last year. This year I may be learning scala and would then setup another blog called scalatutorial. Is ot forbidden to take the name of one's blog as alias ?!!!

Sunanda has nothing to do with me, he doesn't even know me and conversely.

Comment: I checked out Rebol Tutorial's blog `http://reboltutorial.com/blog` - I see no evidence that R.T. is "seeding" questions simply for the purpose of reposting the material for blog entries. That is, R.T.'s questions look like legit questions.

Answer (score 0):

Linking to anything relevant that will help the OP is perfectly acceptable (in my book, anyway). I write a lot of tutorials that are published under the CC-BY-SA license or something even less restrictive. Some of them are ten pages long. Some may be prone to change as the subject changes, that's just the nature of software. If I think it will help, I'll link to my own site in an answer before I end up maintaining 10 copies of the same text.

On or off SO, if its helpful, I won't complain if someone makes a link. However, I can't speak for everyone.

Linking to other answers on SO is quite common.

I would not link to something that people weren't free to copy or distribute, which includes any page you can find on SO. The people who vote on my answers can decide if my idea of helpful coincides with the community.

Why were you worried?